# CSS Media Query not working with Ipad device

Tags: html, css

I am trying to create some text that would show on Mobile Devices with 415px some text and on Ipad 768px it would show a different text.
And the problem is that the text of iPhone it shows on Ipad too and the Ipad text it doesn't show at all and I need some help so I can show on Ipad Device the text I have created and on iPhone Device it would show the iPhone text, because I've been struggling with this for long and still wasn't able how to fix this.
Thank you.

```css
body{
  background: grey;
  height: 900px;
}
.webdev{
    width: 100%;
    height: 350px;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-size: cover;
  background: rgb(140, 253, 191);
}
.txt1{
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 88%;
    left: 5%;
    color: red;
    font-size: 35px;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    font-weight: 980;
}
.ipadtext1{
    color: black;
    font-size: 45px;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    font-weight: 980;
}
.txt2{
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 82%;
    left: 5%;
    color: red;
    font-size: 35px;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    font-weight: 980;
}
.ipadtext2{
    color: black;
    font-size: 45px;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    font-weight: 980;
}
.ipadtext3{
    color: black;
    font-size: 45px;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    font-weight: 980;
}
.txt3{
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 76%;
    left: 5%;
    color: red;
    font-size: 35px;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    font-weight: 980;
}
.ipadhireme{
    font-size: 19px;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    padding: 18px;
    background-color: black;
    padding-left: 35px;
    padding-right: 35px;
    letter-spacing: 1px;
    transition: .3s ease-in-out;
    color: white;
}
.ipadhireme a{
    text-decoration: none;
    color: white;
}
.ipadhireme:hover{
    background-color: red;
    color: white;
}
.hireme{
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 68%;
    left: 5%;
    font-size: 19px;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    padding: 18px;
    background-color: yellow;
    padding-left: 35px;
    padding-right: 35px;
    letter-spacing: 1px;
    transition: .3s ease-in-out;
    color: black;
}
.hireme a{
    text-decoration: none;
    color: white;
}
.hireme:hover{
    background-color: red;
    color: black;
}
.ipadtext1,.ipadtext2,.ipadtext3,.ipadhireme{
    display: none;
}

@media screen and (max-width: 415px) {
    .webdev{
        height: 300px;
    }
    .txt1,.txt2,.txt3,.hireme{
        display: block;
    }
    .ipadtext1,.ipadtext2,.ipadtext3,.ipadhireme{
        display: none;
    }
    .hireme{
        position: absolute;
        bottom: 59%;
    }
    .txt1,.txt2,.txt3{
        font-size: 30px;
    }
    .txt1{
    }
    .txt2{
    }
    .txt3{
    }

}
}

@media screen and (max-width: 768px) {
    .ipadwebdev{
        height: 65%;
    }
    .txt1,.txt2,.txt3,.hireme{
        display: none;
    }
    .ipadtext1,.ipadtext2,.ipadtext3,.ipadhireme{
        display: block;
    }
    .ipadtext1{
        bottom: 70%;
        font-size: 70px;
    }
    .ipadtext2{
        bottom: 61.4%;
        font-size: 70px;
    }
    .ipadtext3{
        bottom: 53%;
        font-size: 64px;
    }
    .ipadhireme{
        bottom: 43%;
    }
   
}
```

```html
    <div class="menuja">
        <div class="webdev">
        <div class="txt1">Mobile Text</div>
        <div class="txt2">Mobile Text</div>
        <div class="txt3">Mobile Text.</div>
        <a href="contact.html"><button class="hireme">Mobile</button></a>

        <div class="ipadtext1">Ipad Text</div>
        <div class="ipadtext2">Ipad Text</div>
        <div class="ipadtext3">Ipad Text.</div>
        <a href="contact.html"><button class="ipadhireme">Lorem Ipsum</button></a>
    </div>
```

Comment: Not Sure Will This Help You or not, Please Checkout This Link.
The problem might be the breakpoints.
http://stephen.io/mediaqueries/

Answer (score 0):

I am sure it does not answer your question, but take it as a suggestion: It is much simpler if you apply your breakpoints putting mobile devices first. And is more friendly for mobile devices.
This way you don't need to overwrite your CSS rules so much

```css
// This applies from 0px to 600px
body {
  background: red;
}

// This applies from 600px onwards
@media (min-width: 600px) {
  body {
    background: green;
  }
}
```

Sorry if that doesnt help you, but this is a good practice that may help you.

Answer (score 0):

The breakpoints you use do not fit on modern iPad screens. Please use the following media queries instead:

```
/* iPads (portrait and landscape) ----------- */
@media only screen and (min-device-width : 768px) and (max-device-width : 1024px) {
/* Styles */
}

/* iPads (landscape) ----------- */
@media only screen and (min-device-width : 768px) and (max-device-width : 1024px) and (orientation : landscape) {
/* Styles */
}

/* iPads (portrait) ----------- */
@media only screen and (min-device-width : 768px) and (max-device-width : 1024px) and (orientation : portrait) {
/* Styles */
}
/**********
iPad 3 and newer devices (excluding iPad Pro)
**********/
@media only screen and (min-device-width : 768px) and (max-device-width : 1024px) and (orientation : landscape) and (-webkit-min-device-pixel-ratio : 2) {
/* Styles */
}

@media only screen and (min-device-width : 768px) and (max-device-width : 1024px) and (orientation : portrait) and (-webkit-min-device-pixel-ratio : 2) {
/* Styles */
}

/**********
iPad Pro 12.9"
**********/
/* Landscape*/
@media only screen and (min-device-width: 1366px) and (max-device-height: 1024px) and (-webkit-min-device-pixel-ratio: 2)  and (orientation: landscape)  {}

/* Portrait*/
@media only screen and (min-device-width: 1024px) and (max-device-height: 1366px) and (-webkit-min-device-pixel-ratio: 2)  and (orientation: portrait)  {}

/**********
iPad Pro 10.5"
**********/
/* Landscape*/
@media only screen and (min-device-width: 1112px) and (max-device-height: 834px) and (-webkit-min-device-pixel-ratio: 2)  and (orientation: landscape)  {}

/* Portrait*/
@media only screen and (min-device-width: 834px) and (max-device-height: 1112px) and (-webkit-min-device-pixel-ratio: 2)  and (orientation: portrait)  {}
```

Hope this helps.